# É possível carregar templates do undescore externamente com javascript?

Tags: javascript, template, underscore.js

Geralmente, costumo utilizar *Template Engines* para poder renderizar HTML via JavaScript. Uso comumente o `undescore.js`.

Gosto muito dessa maneira de tornar mais fácil a criação de HTML com Templates.

Exemplo:

Em algum lugar do HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-template">
   Meu nome é <b><%= nome %>
</script>
```

No arquivo JS

```
var tplTemplate = _.template($('#tpl-template').html());

$('body').append(tplTemplate({nome: 'Wallace'}));
```

Porém é sempre necessário ter que deixar esse código junto ao código HTML. Eu gostaria de poder organizar esses códigos em um arquivo separado (como um `tpl.js`), por exemplo, porém ainda não consegui uma maneira.

Creio que através do atributo `src` não exista maneira de se fazer isso - se existir me corrijam.

Preciso saber se existe alguma maneira de fazer isso em JavaScript.

Comment: Alguma razão especial para eu ter tomado um -1? Minha pergunta foi tão burra assim?kkkkkk

Comment: Você quer fazer um novo AngularJs. **Ps1** - Não fui eu que negativei. **Ps2** - Você faz muitas perguntas, deve ser por isso o -1. **Ps3** - Não sei a reposta. **Ps4** - Já começou a fabricação nacional, vai baixar o preço.

Comment: Não entendi a PS4.

Comment: Muitas perguntas não é critério para negativo (Ainda bem que a minha esposa não me dá votos negativos) kkkkkk

Comment: http://olhardigital.uol.com.br/noticia/ps4-produzido-no-brasil-ja-esta-a-venda-por-r-2-6-mil/51846

Comment: Critério do SOpt não é, mas pode ser critério de alguém.

Comment: Ps4 foi uma piada... Você tem bom humor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29817/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-deesouza).

Comment: Então quer dizer que o angular já faz isso? valeu pela dica, só fui atinar agora

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o melhor a ser fazer é automatizar o processo de pre-compilação, caso queira saber como faze-lo usando o Grunt, você pode ler mais a respeito neste [link](http://www.codebelt.com/javascript/precompiling-javascript-underscore-templates/);

você também pode pegar o recuperar o script do script acessando a propriedade source através da propriedade source, por exemplo, se fizer isto:

```
console.log(_.template($('#tpl-template').html()).source)
```

você possivelmente terá a seguinte saida:

```
function(obj){
    var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};
    with(obj||{}){
        __p+='    Meu nome é <b>'+
            ((__t=( nome ))==null?'':__t)+
            '</b>\n';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

então basicamente você apenas precisaria ter o seguinte codigo em um arquivo JS separado:

```
var templates = {};
templates.meuNome = function(obj){
    var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};
    with(obj||{}){
        __p+='    Meu nome é <b>'+
            ((__t=( nome ))==null?'':__t)+
            '</b>\n';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

no seu script principal, você apenas teria de usar o `templates.meuNome({nome: 'Wallace'})`, sem a necessidade de ter a tag `script#tpl-template` na pagina.

por fim um pequeno exemplo com um utilitario para gerar os Scripts:

```js
var textTemplate = document.getElementById("textTemplate");
var textPreCompiled = document.getElementById("textPreCompiled");
var txtNomeTemplate = document.getElementById("txtNomeTemplate");
var btPrecompilar = document.getElementById("btPrecompilar");

btPrecompilar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var tmplSource = textTemplate.value;
    var template = _.template(tmplSource);

    textPreCompiled.value = "var " + txtNomeTemplate.value + " = " + template.source;
});
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<textarea id="textTemplate">
  Meu nome é <b><%= nome %></b>
</textarea>
<label>
  Nome template:
  <input id="txtNomeTemplate" type="text" value="tplTemplate" />
</label>
<input id="btPrecompilar" type="button" value="PreCompilar Template" />
<textarea id="textPreCompiled">

</textarea>
<script type="text/template" id="tmplNome">

</script>
```